# mongodb find nested field not work in php

Tags: php, mongodb

i am new on php and mongodb. i want to find all data which match the condition in php. 
the following mongodb structure:

```
'Food' => 
array (size=4)
  '_id' => 
    object(MongoId)[36]
      public '$id' => string '587e4a89974711036c97d3e5' (length=24)
  'CaseId' => string 'c002' (length=4)
  'Level' => string '4' (length=1)
  'food' => string 'banana' (length=6)
```

i try to search 'food' value in Food object. i have do some research. i have some method to deal with. however, i cannot find anything. i don't know where wrong? hope someone can teach me.
here is my query:

```
$cursor=$collection->find(array("Food.food"=>array('$in'=>["banana"])));

$cursor=$collection->find(array('Food'=>array('food'=>"banana")));
$cursor=$collection->find(array('Food.food'=>"banana"));
```

after i research, i know MongoDB supports dot notation. resource from
[enter link description here](https://www.sitepoint.com/mongodb-revisited/) 
also i find some get nested field method from 
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106424/mongo-query-a-nested-field-within-an-array/37106446#37106446)
i following the link 2 to typing in mongodb compass. i can get the result i want, but when i follow the structure to enter in php. it have not any result.
what happen in these code?? i am confused. thank you.

Comment: the third commented line must work. How do you check a result of a query?

Comment: In program, I have not enter "//" in the first character.  Maybe I modify it.

Answer (score 0):

i find other method to solve this problem. if someone meet this case like me, you can try below method.

```
$query= array(  
'$match'=>array('Food.food'=>'banana')
);

$cursor=$collection->aggregate($query);
```

you can type `$cursor['result']` to receive the searching result.