# MongoDB match a subdocument inside array (not positional reference)

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB has a key-value pair structure, inside my document has a `data` field which is an array that contains many subdocuments of two fields: `name` and `value`.

How do I search for a subdocument e.g ( `{"name":"position", "value":"manager"}`) and also multiple (e.g. `{"name":"age", "value" : {$ge: 30}}`)

EDIT: I am not looking for a specific subdocument as I mentioned in title (not positional reference), rather, I want to retrieve the entire document but I need it to match the two subdocuments exactly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: No, I don't want to find a specific subdocument, I want to retrieve the entire record. But my question is how do I query using a subdocument in an array.

Comment: Understood. Use `$elemMatch` query variant. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/ & https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Comment: Thanks @Veeram, is there any example if I want to query multiple elemMatch, is it using $and operator?

Comment: Np. Here you go. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#use-all-with-elemmatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 queries to find the following record:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("sometobjectID"), 
    "data" : [
        {
            "name" : "position", 
            "value" : "manager"
        }
    ]
}

// Both value and name (in the same record):
db.demo.find({$elemMatch: {"value": "manager", "name":"position"}})


// Both value and name (not necessarily in the same record):
db.demo.find({"data.value": "manager", "data.name":"position"})


// Just value:    
db.demo.find({"data.value": "manager"})
```

Note how the `.` is used, this works for all subdocuments, even if they are in an array.

You can use any operator you like here, including `$gte`

***edit***

$elemMatch added to answer because of @[Veeram's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683814/veeram) response

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335248/dot-notation-vs-elemmatch) explains the difference between `$elemMatch` and `.`

Comment: Awesome. In that case, @cherhan would you mind up voting the answer. ?